# Object of the Canvas class not being created in kivy python

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I was trying to create an object of the Canvas() class of kivy.graphics. It should've created a rectangle but it displays nothing. I tried to find a solution and I goone of those was to import the Canvas class from kivy.uix.widget and then use self.add_widget(canvas1) but it gave an error saying add_widget only works for instances of the widget class. The thing below is my entire code-

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle,Canvas

class Main(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    canvas1=Canvas()
    with canvas1:
        Rectangle(size=[1000,400])

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

MyApp().run()
```